# Anet A8 won't print

Tags: 3d-models, extruder, pla, anet-a8

I have just built my Anet A8 and it won't print.

I will preheat it (190°C 60°C) and then press "`Print File`" and select, then it starts for a second, gets to around 11% and stops and shows "`Preheat PLA`". The PLA is already preheated - it is coming out of the nozzle.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the "file" you're trying to print look like? How was it generated? Can you post the first few lines (up to and including the first few G1 commands) here?

Comment: Make sure the thermistor isn't loose in the extruder block. If  it even "wobbles" in its mount, the reported temperature will go awry.

Comment: Looks like you have a faulty Arduino or something on the board or nozzle assembly is loose. When the machine stops does it show any message?

Comment: This _may_ be useful, [Print won't start, stuck at 0% forever](http://forums.reprap.org/read.php?406,715111) - in particular the advice regarding the `M190`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem last week where the thermostat's heat shrink was being melted by the block and the two wires were touching. I fixed this by securing the thermistor and putting a thermal insulator between the block and the wires. I also put a small piece of heat shrink between the wires to insulate them so they will never touch. Thank you and I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer has a sound foundation in your explanation. If the thermistor is shorting, it would result in an inaccurate reading to the processor. Your solution is also simple enough to implement as a test.

Answer (score 0):

The Anet A8 files that come preloaded are `.stl` so if you try to print those it will say printing zero percent and then just switch right back to preheating PLA without any error message. Download a free slicer tool if that's the case.

Comment: mine came with gcode on the sdcard...